# sonar-scanner-2.9.0.670 throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError inside docker container

Tags: docker, sonarqube, travis-ci

In this build inside docker (on travis-ci), sonar-scanner-2.9.0.670 throws a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:166)enter code here
```

Build log here (see line 4660):
https://travis-ci.org/laristra/flecsi/jobs/213157927#L4660

Sonarqube got put into a `ubuntu:latest` container here:
https://github.com/laristra/flecsi-buildenv/blob/sonarqube/ubuntu#L14

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? On which SonarQube instance are you trying to run and push the analysis? As you're working on an OSS project, why don't you try to use SonarQube.com and follow http://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/ ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to push to sonarqube.com, my properties files is this one: https://github.com/laristra/flecsi/blob/sonarqube/sonar-project.properties

Comment: I really don't understand why you need to have a Docker container for that purpose... Please read my answer below. Things are much easier than what you try to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, we cannot build on Travis-CI natively as their images misses most of flecsi's dependencies and we wouldn't be able to build them all on the fly in time. For this reason we cannot use the SonarQube analysis Travis Addon.

Answer (score 0):

You are working on a C++ project: https://github.com/laristra/flecsi. 
You are building it with Travis-CI.
You want to analyze it on SonarQube.com.

You don't need to download any SonarQube Scanner nor set up any SonarQube inside a Docker.

Please:

- follow the [Get Started guide](https://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/)
- , and look at the [sample C/C++ project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_c-sqscanner-travis) to understand how to trigger a SonarQube analysis using our Travis Addon

  - It automatically downloads and installs the SonarQube Scanner
  - It automatically downloads and installs the C/C++ Build Wrapper
  - It automatically configure everything to point to SonarQube.com

Comment: For the reason mentioned above we have to use docker for building and after switching to openjdk everything worked as expected. I made a little toy project https://github.com/junghans/travis-docker-glue , which utilizes Docker, Travis-CI, SonarQube and Codecov.io.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was Oracle's JDK using openjdk-8-jdk fixed the issue (inside docker).